# Are values in a Visual Studio's Solution file meant to be unique?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on trying to create a new Visual Studio project, by copying one project into a new folder. (I'm following [this blog post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/27/add-existing-project-to-tfs/).) I'd also like to rename the project. I've renamed the .sln file. After renaming the .sln file I opened it and found lines like this:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CoreFramework", "CoreFramework\CoreFramework.csproj", "{FFC117EB-6987-4C5F-B3CF-D6ECDD660827}"
```

I'm wondering if those GUIDs need to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first GUID is the project type. The second is the project id GUID and should be unique.

```
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-PROJECTTYPE0}") = "MyProject",
"MyProject.csproj", "{8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-UNIQUE000000}"
EndProject
```

[Solution (.sln) file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Sebastian, what happens if I don't change that first GUID?

Comment: I was wrong with the order, the answer is corrected. I was trying it with VS2019 and it is smart enough to recognize this and makes the project id unique again.

Comment: I'm using VS 2017, but also have VS 2019. I'll open it with VS 2019 and hope that it "fixes" it.

Comment: I tried it also with 2017. Both versions didn't even mention it.

Comment: I've opened the .sln in the new TFS project with VS 2019. Then I got out and compared the old .sln with the new .sln, using WinMerge. They're identical. :(

Comment: Ah, I used one solution with two projects. So they have to be unique within the solution.  After a few tries, it seems like VS just generates a new GUID for every new project. No matter if it is a different solution or not.

Comment: Then maybe it won't matter. I've no intention of copying the original project again into the new solution.